# Allowing users create tables on the fly using laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, eloquent, database-migration

I am building an new application using Laravel and i want the user/owner to be able to create registration forms for each event the owner has created.

The application allows the owner create an event then associate a registration form to be filled by interested attendees... The form fields would be decided upon by the owner of the event and the data would be stored in the new table created.

If there is any other way to achieve this.. i'm open to suggestion pls

Comment: So, you're creating phpmyadmin on laravel?

Comment: Technically no, i want the admin to create a form to be field the users.. maybe the approach im trying to use is not the best...

Comment: Would you consider using a document store db rather than a relational one?  If you use something like mongo - then people can re-design their forms without hurting or restructuring the db.

Comment: Definitely... i was considering that but wanted to ask the question here to get expert advice...

Comment: ha - there's maybe 5 experts on the site - I'm not one of them - but for what it's worth - I'd go with nosql.

Comment: Thanks @TarekAdam will look into that...

Comment: better go nosql, giving the application to create and delete tables is just too risky for the overall of the system fyi.. better to have them [execute on the least privilege](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Access_Control).

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is define the form as a JSON or XML, it could be something like:

```
{
  form_name: 'value',
  fields: [
    name: 'string',
    surname: 'string',
    age: 'int'
  ]
}
```

and save it in the database in a table Forms, that has a foreign key (the admin) and a relation M:N with Users. This way you can define the form and register users to the events without the need of adding other tables.

Comment: @pedmindset - this could be a good middle ground, because mysql does support json cols now.

Comment: so the admin create the table by defining the form name and the fields.. then when the users add data, it is saved in the field values as a new row... i'm i getting this right... #AlexCovizzi @TarekAdam

Comment: No, you add the JSON as a column in a table (Events), when an user attends the event the data is saved in a column in the pivot table, between Events and User (UserAttendsEvent)